# Backbone repeated templates with different types

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to figure out the best way to structure the following using Backbone views and templates.  We have a collection of "messages", but the messages may be of different types, each with it's own view.  So, the underlying collection might look like:

```
{ 
  { id: 1, name="message one", type="customer-message" },
  { id: 2, name="message two", type="support-message" },
  { id: 3, name="attachment one", type="attachment" }
}
```

and the resulting page output would be something like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="message customer-message"></li>
  <li class="message support-message"></li>
  <li class="message attachment"></li>
</ul>
```

such that each different li class would have entirely different structure/content.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to set up the templates and Views to a) handle nesting and b) handle the fact that the inner template differs depending on the type.

```
<script type="text/template" id="chat-template">
  <ul>
    <!--how to reference other templates here?-->
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/template" id="customer-message-template">
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="support-message-template">
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="attachment-template">
</script>
```

Not looking for a full solution here - just hoping there's an example someone can point me to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Backbone.Marionette which provides View "subclasses" specifically for handling collection scenarios like this.  http://marionettejs.com/

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it pointed me in the right direction - see my "answer" for more details on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing - essentially using the convention over configuration approach (hat-tip to Robert Levy for Marionette - not sure this couldn't also work with straight backbone, but I think Marionette's CollectionView does make this easier):

```
MyApp.MessageView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    getTemplate: function() {
        var type = this.model.get("type");
        return "#" + type + "-template";
    }
});

MyApp.MessageCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    itemView: MyApp.MessageView,
    tagName: 'ul'
});
```